# BeautifulSoup find links that meet criteria

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to collect all of the links on a webpage I have collected through beautiful soup that contain `/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=`.

Actual links would look like these:

```
"http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234567"
"http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234561"
"http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234564"
"http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234562"
"http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234563"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a [compiled regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) as an `href` argument value to `find_all()`:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'/d2l/lp/ouHome/home\.d2l\?ou=\d+'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <div>
...     <a href="http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234567">link1</a>
...     <a href="http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234561">link2</a>
...     <a href="http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234564">link3</a>
...     <a href="http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234562">link4</a>
...     <a href="http://learn.ou.edu/d2l/lp/ouHome/home.d2l?ou=1234563">link5</a>
... </div>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'/d2l/lp/ouHome/home\.d2l\?ou=\d+'))
>>> for link in links:
...     print link.text
... 
link1
link2
link3
link4
link5
```

Comment: For whatever reason, that isn't working for me. I think it's because the links are inside of the tags, and the tags are at the bottom of the subclasses.

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship ok, then, provide the HTML you are dealing with, or a link to the webpage you are parsing. Thanks.

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship okay, thanks. But, what is the problem with the current code? I've executed it against the HTML you've provided and got 8 different links, starting from `OU IT Tech Bootcamp` to `PSY-1113-001 - Elements of Psychology`..

Comment: hmmm.. okay i may be doing something wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JacksonBlankenship okay, thanks, let me know if you need help debugging what is going on with your code.